# SwiftUI canvas preview displaying multiple views for one view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode-previews

My SwiftUI preview is showing one view as 3 different preview screens and it should be one screen with the combined views...

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

See images attached of 3 separate preview views.[image]

```
struct SignupSelfie: View {
    @ObservedObject var signupImagesViewModel = SignupNavigationViewModel()
    @State private var isValid = false
        
    var body: some View {
      
        VStack {
           Button("capture") { /* action code here */ }
              .background(
                  NavigationLink("", destination: SignupIdView(), isActive: $isValid)
                )
            }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            Spacer()
            Text("capture selfie")
        }
}


struct SignupSelfie_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SignupSelfie()
    }
}
```

Comment: That is happening because your `Spacer()` and `Text("capture selfie")` are outside of the VStack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SwiftUI previews will display a preview for each node at the root of the view tree. This is more clear when it's inside the preview itself, like:

```
struct SignupSelfie_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SignupSelfie()
        SignupSelfie2()
        SignupSelfie3()
    }
}
```

In the above, it's clear why there would be 3 previews.

In your example, as a commenter alluded to, it's happening in your `SignupSelfie` because you have 3 nodes at the root:

1. `VStack`
2. `Spacer()`
3. `Text("capture selfie")`

My guess is the indentation you have may have made it look like the `Spacer` and `Text` were inside the `VStack` -- a good trick is to select your code and use `Ctrl-i` to have Xcode auto-format -- it'll fix indentation issues like this and reveal the issue.

In this case, you'll probably just want to put everything inside the `VStack`. In other cases, it's good to know that you can also avoid this issue and turn multiple nodes into one by wrapping them in `Group {}`

Comment: Thanks for the fix and explanation (altough, I'm personally at a loss as to why the entire `var body....` isn't just viewed as a single node - isn't that it's point in a released app....?). In my instance `Group` also did the same thing and it had to be a `ZStack`.